# textfield as input for webservice

Tags: java, web-services, user-interface

I'm trying to make an application (gui) that has one input field and one output field.

I'm trying to make it so that the text I write in the input field will be forwarded to a web service, and the result I get from the web service should be displayed in the output field.

I thought I had a grasp on how to do it but, know I'm just sitting here staring at the screen with a blank mind.

I have made the gui (gui.java) and have some of the controller (controller.java).

I just can't connect the dots between how I'm supposed to call for the web service from a textfield and then present the findings in another textfield (or something).

Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I've got so far:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.CardLayout;

import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;

import webservicefile.control.Controller;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class window {

    private JFrame frame;
    private Controller control;
    private JTextField txtInput;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */


    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public window(Controller control) {
        this.control = control;
        initialize();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        txtInput = new JTextField();
        txtInput.setBounds(116, 30, 207, 28);
        panel.add(txtInput);
        txtInput.setColumns(10);

        JTextArea txtDisplay = new JTextArea();
        txtDisplay.setBounds(116, 133, 207, 121);
        panel.add(txtDisplay);

        JButton btnSend = new JButton("Send");
        btnSend.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                final String input = txtInput.getText();
                final String display = control.send(input);
                txtDisplay.setText(display);
            }
        });
        btnSend.setBounds(334, 31, 96, 28);
        panel.add(btnSend);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an "OK/send" button that has a [java.awt.event.ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html), or else add a [java.awt.event.KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) to the text field that will listen for key events.

In either case, when the listener is triggered you would then get the content of the text field and pass it to the WS client.

Some examples, slightly in pseudocode, in which WebServiceClient is a notional class that provides WS support...

**Using an ActionListener**

```
public void configureUI(final WebServiceClient client) {
    JTextField inputField = new JTextField();
    JTextArea responseArea = new JTextArea();
    JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");

    sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            final String text = inputField.getText();
            final String response = client.send(text);
            responseArea.setText(response);
        }
    });

    // add inputField, responseArea and sendButton to the container
}
```

**Alternatively, using a KeyListener**

```
public void configureUI(final WebServiceClient client) {
    JTextField inputField = new JTextField();
    JTextArea responseArea = new JTextArea();

    inputField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                final String text = inputField.getText();
                final String response = client.send(text);
                responseArea.setText(response);
            }
        }
    });

    // add inputField, responseArea and sendButton to the container
}
```

This should be enough to get you going, but still give you some things to learn.

Comment: OK great, excuse my ignorance (I'm a total java-newb) but how would that look like in code? (Tried reading the link but didn't make my any wiser) Like txtListen = new JTextField(keyListener) or something?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Should I have a send button in either case? And also, this should be placed in my gui.java and not in my controller.java right?

Comment: I would have both, because then you can hit return or click the button to trigger the WS call.  The behaviour should come from the controller, so instead of passing WebServiceClient in, pass in a function that's invoked by the listeners; this function wraps the WS call.

Comment: Whatever you do, start simple and build from there!

Comment: I've edited my OP to show what I've got so far. Something doesn't work on these two lines: -     final String display = control.send(input); (send is marked red)   -   txtDisplay.setText(display); (txtDisplay) is red). Also I feel that I'm missing something. Thanks

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say that send either doesn't exist or doesn't have visibilty;  txtDisplay needs to be final so it can be visible in the anonymous implementation of ActionListener.